# What is the default datatype for numpy floats?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, some numpy functions want me to specify datatype, like np.fromiter(). What am I supposed to choose for floats so that it is consistent with everything else I have?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know what the default datatype is (as in the question), or do you want to make it compatible to floats (as per the text)?

Comment: `np.float` is `np.float64` internally. Using `np.float` or `float` in Numpy arrays is deprecated. So for an array of floats consider using `np.float64` unless it is ok to use a smaller precision (like `np.float32`).

Comment: @JérômeRichard `float` is not deprecated. Actually, if you try `np.arange(10, dtype=np.float)` you'll get the following: `DeprecationWarning: np.float is a deprecated alias for the builtin float. To silence this warning, use float by itself.`

Comment: @paime Indeed for `float`, it does not raise a warning, but please do not use it. It causes more checks to be done in less efficient portions of the code causing slower execution (also due to inefficient CPython types) though the overhead is generally small (not to mention it makes the implementation more complex and this is a pain to work on this kind of code and optimize it). Numpy types like `np.float_` (which refers to `np.float64`) or precise types should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float`, the Python built-in type. NumPy understands that (and will use C doubles under the hood, which is exactly what Python itself does as well).